# manage images issue Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, image

I have a problem to understand how do I manage the various image resolution in iOS with Swift.

For example if I have an image that i use it in my app , I have to create to for various devices resolution , but after that I insert in my project the various image resolution where I have to insert it, in a special folder?.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply drag your images with different resolutions from finder to the Asset Catalog in Xcode.

First, you need to understand why images with 1x, 2x, and 3x resolutions are needed.

Some devices' screen have denser pixels than others. These devices have what is called "Retina Displays". Imagine that you want to display a 100px by 100px image on a normal display. Now imagine that the same image is displayed on a display where the pixels are more closely packed. Obviously, the image on the second display will appear smaller. That's not a very good user experience.

To solve this problem, you can provide 2x and 3x images. The operating system will automatically choose to use these images whenever the display is a retina display.

Now let's see how you can put the images into Xcode.

First open your asset catalog:

[image]q

Then drag the image that you want to add to this panel:

[image]

Then you will see that your image is added:[image]

Now do you see those 1x 2x 3x thingys? That's where you need to drag the images with higher resolutions to!

So here I dragged a 2x image to the 2x slot:

[image]

Now when your app runs on a device with retina display, the 2x image will be used!

Comment: I have a doubt : if In my app I have an image view , for it I use the basic(1x) image and the system when execute on retina display change it to 2x image?

Comment: Yes that's right! iOS is smart. You don't need to worry about _when_ it will choose the 2x image. Just put it there and you'll be fine! @gianni

Comment: ok when I create I do : UIImage(named:"baseImage.png") and when app run on retina display system changes baseImage.png with baseImage@2x.png?  is it right?

Comment: Yes! @gianni You'll be fine! try it out!

Comment: @gianni If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking that tick/checkmark thingy!

Answer (score 0):

It's rather not for image resolution but screen's pixel density. Basically you've got non-retina devices (standard) and retina ( 2xstandard and 3xstandard). So, in example if you've got 100x100 point imageView that you would like to feed with image named square.png asset you will need 3 kind of images: square.png (100x100px), square@2x.png (200x200px) and square@3x.png (300x300px).

In Xcode, put these images in something called Asset Catalog - it will handle images' size managing for you.

More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/_index.html

Comment: ok , but when I create an image in my code I use the basic image and the system automatically change the image based on device?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you're creating images in code you can create them right in proper size - because you've got all info you need to do so.